# what is it called when encrypt('a') || encrypt('a') == encrypt('aa')?

Tags: encryption, terminology, ssh, programming-interface

So normally if you do `encrypt('a')` twice in a row you'll get the same result. But sometimes (as is the case in SSH) this is not desirable. You want `encrypt('a') || encrypt('a') == encrypt('aa')`. What is this called?

PHP does it with mcrypt:

```
<?php 
$mcrypt = mcrypt_module_open(MCRYPT_DES, '', MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, '');
mcrypt_generic_init($mcrypt, '@@@@@@@@', 'xxxxxxxx'); 
echo bin2hex(mcrypt_generic($mcrypt, 'dddddddd')); 
echo "\r\n"; 
echo bin2hex(mcrypt_generic($mcrypt, 'dddddddd'));
```

eg. you're encrypting dddddddd twice but getting a different result each time.

PHP does not do it with OpenSSL:

```
echo bin2hex(openssl_encrypt('dddddddd', 'des-cbc', '@@@@@@@@', OPENSSL_RAW_DATA | OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING, 'xxxxxxxx')); 
echo "\r\n"; 
echo bin2hex(openssl_encrypt('dddddddd', 'des-cbc', '@@@@@@@@', OPENSSL_RAW_DATA | OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING, 'xxxxxxxx'));
```

Given the API it makes since that OpenSSL wouldn't do it. It can certainly be emulated by changing the IV's but you'd have to do it manually.

Anyway, what is this called? Is it called progressive encryption? Continuous encryption?

Comment: What has the mentioned "encrypt('a') + encrypt('a') == encrypt('aa')" to do with the question? I don't really know what you're asking. Dou you want an encryption which would have two added (adding like in a sum or adding like in concatenating?) encryptions of the same input to be equal to the encryption of the concatenated inputs? Or do you want an encryption which output changes every time you encrypt something? If it is the last: Every good cipher operation mode like CBC should do that.

Comment: yyyyyyy seemed to understand the question just fine. You asked three questions so I'll answer them in order. For #2...  no. I know how to do that. See the first of the two code samples I posted. For #3... see the second code snippet I posted. The output, in that example, does *not* change, even tho I'm encrypting the same thing twice. As I said in my OP this makes since given the API. I was just wanting to know how best to refer to the difference between the two code samples. Both code samples do CBC mode but only one of them gives different outputs for each "block".

Comment: I still have no idea what the whole "encrypt('a') + encrypt('a') == encrypt('aa')" thing has to do with the question. No, I didn't ask three questions. The "last two questions" were only one, a whether-or question. You use two different cipher suits and get different output. Sounds pretty clear for me. Look for the definition of the two functions.

Comment: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/21438bc9076bbb12830bf6aebaa37bfd958567d4 When I execute that code v1 and v2 are the same (ie. `encrypt('a') + encrypt('a') == encrypt('aa')`) but v3 isn't. I am *not* asking why. I *know* why. yyyyyyy's post elaborates as to the *why*. I am wanting to know if there is a *name* for this behavior. And as for using two different cipher suites... idk what you're talking about. They're both des-cbc. Take a second look at the first code snippet and you'll see `mcrypt_module_open(MCRYPT_DES, '', MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, '')`. MCRYPT_MODE_CBC means cbc - not ecb etc

Comment: No, cipher suit like in openssl and mcrypt, not operation mode. And I have no idea what v1, v2 and v3 should be. The mentioned code fragment should never result true, because it doesn't make sense to add the output of two block cipher encryptions.

Comment: I think this is a question you should ask in math.stackexchange.com, as a name for this is probably not something crypto-specific. Edit: Just found this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy's_functional_equation

Comment: @Nova - +, in this case, is representing the concatenation operation - not addition. Why would you assume it means addition when, as you said, that doesn't make any sense? That's like me saying "can I do this?" and then someone else saying that that sentence doesn't make sense because can is a noun. "a usually metal typically cylindrical receptacle usually with an open top". I mean, if you have two different definitions why would you assume it's the one that *doesn't* make sense?

Comment: @neubert: Concatenation only makes sense if we assume that a is exactly one block wide and the whole function doesn't has any further padding. The whole code is not purposeful, the whole question would be easier if you write: "How is the characteristic called if "encrypt('a') || encrypt('a') == encrypt('aa')" for "a" as a whole block and "encrypt" as normal block cipher with zero padding." (I did change the + to ||. That's (as far as I know) more common for concatenation.

Comment: @Nova - fair enough!

Comment: @neubert To be fair, I was also confused what you meant.  You're in a forum with a variety of backgrounds.  Most of us aren't PHP programmers and don't assume the + operator means string concatenation.  There's a danger in assuming a context that "makes sense".  It might make sense to you in a certain context, but you're always making assumptions for it to "make sense".  That's why people prefer well defined problems, since you don't have to make assumptions that may or may not be accurate.

Comment: @Steve Sether - good point. Although technically in PHP string concatenation is done with the dot operator (`.`). I did `+` because it seems that that's more common for string concatenation than `.`. Java, Javascript and C++ all use `+` for string concatenation. But I think in this forum `||` would have made the most sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there is a dedicated name for this. If I had to find a word, it would probably be "stateful" or "with explicit state". What you observe is actually the *usual* case: The user initializes an encryption system with a key, resulting in some **state** of the system. Then, each time the user wishes to encrypt some data, he has to pass the current state along with it and the state gets updated by the encryption function. This way, one can encrypt messages that arrive in multiple pieces over time, resulting in greater flexibility (think live streaming!).

In your `mcrypt` example, the initialization is performed by `mcrypt_generic_init`, the state is stored in `$mcrypt`, and encryption is done by `mcrypt_generic`. In other languages, the state is encapsuled in "cipher objects", like those provided by, for instance, Python's `Crypto.Cipher.*` classes.

**Then**, there are *special* functions, like the OpenSSL example you provided, that are designed to encrypt just one single blob of data. They accept a key and a message as an argument and perform state initialization and encryption in one step, afterwards discarding the state and returning the ciphertext. The state is not exposed to the user, so he cannot continue encrypting more data. These functions exist solely for convenience, providing a simpler interface for the common case of encrypting one opaque message.

Comment: The user doesn't quite initialize with a _key_, they initialize with an _IV_ (normally). The difference is that an IV is not secret.

Comment: That's not true. The user *always* supplies a key (what else would the algorithm use to encrypt data?), and depending on the particular cryptosystem, an IV *may* be needed in addition. This is of course heavily implementation-dependent, so other views might be valid as well.

Comment: But the key isn't used to initialize the state, at least for block ciphers; the state would be what carries over between blocks (changing with each block), while the key is the same for all blocks.

Comment: For instance, ECB has a key but is not stateful in this sense; the nonsecret IV is what lets CBC and other good modes achieve multiple ciphertexts for one plaintext and key.

Comment: Well, I guess we are both right. I was talking mainly about the way things are usually *implemented*, since the question was a very practical one (and `mcrypt_generic_init`, among many more examples, *does* expect both key and IV). You are right that in theoretical contexts, one usually does not consider the key part of the state; I guess this discrepancy is due to theory arguing mostly about *one* key/communication while implementations might have to deal with many simultaneous connections using different keys, so it is quite obvious to keep the key in the cipher state.

Comment: That seems like a good summary.

Comment: Java has separate `update` functions that operate on the current state. Then you call `doFinal` which returns the state of the object to the one directly after calling `init`. So streaming is supported, but you'd still get a reset of each state for each separate full encryption. You can wonder if this is a good default; you'd probably rather have a random IV for each state as .NET does. Anyway, these kind of design decisions are part of the API design of each runtime; there are more than the two options you discuss in the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Your example is missing something: your two calls to the OpenSSL library are entirely entirely independent, but your calls to the `mcrypt` library reuse an existing handle. CBC has the property that identical plaintext blocks are exceedingly unlikely to encrypt to the same value due to chaining of the previous output into the next input.

Your OpenSSL calls cannot do this, because you are not preserving the CBC state between calls; two independent instances of the cipher are being initialized and used.

Additionally, even in independent calls, you almost *never* want `encrypt('a') == encrypt('a')`; this invalidates semantic security, and in many practical cryptosystems it allows an attacker to conduct a blockwise-adaptive chosen plaintext attack, which reveals the non-chosen plaintext contents. This is the fundamental reason why encryption modes use initialization vectors (which are non-secret, must be unique for the given key, and depending on the mode may need to be unpredictable): to ensure the encryption function has unique inputs even when the plaintext and key are the same.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to yyyyyyy's answer, there is also *probabilistic encryption*, in which the encryption process incorporates some randomness. That allows many identical messages with the same key to be encrypted differently; it doesn't necessarily encrypt the same text differently in the same message (it might encrypt $a+a$ as $E(a)+E(a)$), but it does let you send the same plaintext multiple times with the same key without having it be the same ciphertext.

Probabilistic encryption is often done with stateful ciphers (by using a random and not-secret initialization vector to initialize the state of the cipher); it can also be done with hybrid crypto (a random key for the symmetric encryption), and certain algorithms are *always* probabilistic (e.g. ElGamal). Probabilistic encryption is different than just keeping track of state; you can do probabilistic encryption without keeping track of state (e.g. if you do hybrid encryption and your symmetric encryption is done in ECB mode, so within one message two identical blocks encrypt identically), and can keep track of state without doing probabilistic encryption (e.g. CBC mode with a fixed IV).

You mention that you'd have to change the IVs to get OpenSSL to do this; that's because you're *supposed* to change the IV every time you encrypt a new message. IVs are not secret, so you can just generate a new one for every message.